# Using OpenCV in Parse Cloud Code

Tags: android, python, opencv, parse-platform

This will be my new post if I go wrong please don't judge me hard :)

I'm developing an OpenCV project with Python and also I'm developing its mobile interface in Android. My purpose is to compare plant pictures and decide their species.Researchers who use Android application will take plant photos and upload them (such as 'tree leaf photo'). I intent to execute comparison algorithms in the cloud. I use Parse as mobile database so I thought that I could use Cloud Code in Parse to run my Python codes. Can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have Parse Cloud Code call out to your Python code using HTTP if you want. Just as you can do the same from the Android app. This code can tell the web hook what images to download and process based on some condition (such as a researcher has uploaded a photo to be processed). Purely up to you how you trigger this. Your Cloud Code is JavaScript only though, same as your Android app is Java only (usually, unless you use Xamarin with C# or something else of course).

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I will try your solution. I've used REST APIs of Parse to download the files I need, process them and upload results to Parse again. But I have to always listen what's happening on Parse. I think my solution is more amateur then yours :)

Answer (score 0):

No. JavaScript is the only language currently supported for writing CloudCode.

Comment: Is there any suggestion you can give about how to compare taken photos from Android devices ? I will have multiple users and I have to process their pictures real-time with a dataset of images. Using another cloud provider for example ?